# OPENCV Problems saving a raw matrix in cvMat (C) and plotting it

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I'm getting crazy with this problem in OpenCv. I have to read a raw image, saved as an array in a binary file, and save it in the cvMat structure prepared in opencv. I did, and seems it works, I can access to the data. But I can't plot it. It appears as a lot of diagonal lines. I have printed the numbers in the data matrix, and seems to be correct, except that some 0's appear sometimes. This tell me that something with the 'step' field is running but I have no idea.

I write here the code I have, I hope some of you understand what is happening. Thanks a lot in advance! Omg.

```
#include <stdio.h>//printf;fread...
#include <stdlib.h>//malloc,calloc ...
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
// READING IMAGES
int read_raw_image(FILE* filehandler,float*** datamatrix,int* height,int* width);
//THIS READ THE RAW FILE SAVING THE DATA IN A MATRIX [HEIGHT][WIDTH]
char image_file[]="IR.raw";
CvMat image;

//RUBBISH FOR READ THE IMAGE
FILE *Fimage;
int height,width;
float **pimage=(float**)malloc(sizeof(float**));
if((Fimage=fopen(image_file,"rb"))!= NULL)
{
    printf("\n\tFile: %s was opened correctly\n",image_file);
    read_raw_image(Fimage,&pimage,&height,&width);
    fclose(Fimage);
}
else {printf("\n\tFile: %s wasn't opened correctly\n",image_file);return 0;}

//NOW THE PROBLEM
image=cvMat(height,width,CV_32FC1,*pimage);//HEIGHT=640; WIDTH=480; THE NUMBERS ARE FLOATS
printf("%i",image.step);//THE NUMBER GIVEN IS 1920 (480*4)
int i,j;
for(j = 0;j<2;j++)//print just two rows
{
    for(i = 0;i<480;i++)
{
    printf("%f\n",cvmGet(image,j,i));/The numbers showed are well, except some 0's in the middle
        if(*(Aux->data.fl+(j*640)+i)<10)
    {
      printf("piiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii\n");//MAKE EASY TO SEE THE 0'S
    }
}
     printf("fila:%i\n",j);//Print the number of row at the end
}
 //AND NOW PLOT IT!
cvNamedWindow("win1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("win1",&image);
cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
```

I have no idea what can be the problem with the image.step values. I test to changed it. When I add more, some 0's dissapear, but the image is no printed also.

Thanks for your help. Omg

P.D: The plot... I can't post images!

Comment: How mamy are the channels of the image? `image.step` should be `image_width * number_of_channels`. And also are you sure that the channels in the raw file are BGR as opencv expects ?

Comment: Hi! Just one. The image is an array of temperatures from a IR camera.

Comment: I am getting something. It seems that for some performance, each row has 4 0's at the end. So at the begining of the second row, there are 4 0's; In the third one there are again 4 0's from 4 to 8 positions, and so on. The curious thing, it's I can avoid read this 0's in the direct way of get data. For example:int i,j;for(i = 0;i<640;i++)
{for(j = 0;j<480;j++)
{printf("[%i,%i]=%f\n",i,j,*(Aux->data.fl+(i*(480+4))+j));}} But with cvmGet(&image,i,j) The 0's appear. What I'm thinking, each image line is somehow displaced and that's why only appear the diagonal lines. But how to solve it? NO idea.

Comment: May be the lines are padded with zeros at the end.

Comment: Yes, they have four 0's at the end of each row, but ¿why? and the worst, how cvShowImage can avoid it? ;Of course, thanks for your answers...

Comment: I think those zeroes are padding in the raw file you read. You could either : 1) add 4 to the width `image` (the one you show): that way you get the right image with a black stripe on the right OR 2) You could write the data from the `pimage` to `image` row by row instead of passing it a pointer to float array.

Comment: Also Float images in OpenCV have colours from 0 to 1(0-black, 1-white). This means that you have to rescale the image to fit in there. This is the documentation for CvConvertScale : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#convertscale

Comment: ¡Thanks Dimitar! With your idea, I decided read again the raw image, but in just one dimension array. I pass it to cvMat structure,and knowing the height and weight, the get and show functions work perfectly. As you said, the image was white, but with the rescaling, it appears! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You should write the answer anyway so that someone else might find it easier then reading all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieve the solutions thanks to Dimitar. By some reason,each row finished with a float 0's, this made an offset in each line, represented in the plot as four black dots. Since each line is now displaced, the result was a displaced 4 black dots, that seemed a diagonal line. The explanation for this 0's at the end should be the way I saved the array (It doesn't appear in the code) as a 2D dinamically allocated array, where first I allocated the number of rows, and later each row separatedly. However, the best way to save the images is in a 1D array, allocated just once. When you put it into the cvMat or IplImage, the code runs by rows and columns only with the knowledge of number of rows, number of cols and step (the length in bytes of each row). Also, if I changed the step in the original problem, by 16bytes, I obtain the 0's were not displaces, and stand as a black column in to the right. 
Also it's important to take care that raw files, and in the case of IR cameras, the numbers into the array have to be scaled to a 0-to-1 scale in order to be represented as grayscale plot.
Thanks for your help all.